# How to make a transition effect up the input on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to place this particular effect on a dropdown

I need to place this particular effect on a dropdown where the placeholder goes up and the new vale takes the field, just by using JS, Jquery, CSS and HTML

[Before transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bakp.png)
[After transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewQPS.png)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please post some of your code so we know how to guide you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of input that you wanted is called material design input, where google announced it a few years ago. Chris, on code, describes how to implement this in a good way that you can use or customize by yourself.
you can follow the link below for more information:
[Material Design Input](https://scotch.io/tutorials/google-material-design-input-boxes-in-css3)