# Move label in placeholder CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this sample:

[link](https://codepen.io/cristian-marius/pen/vYBjNoN)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="field">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" class="input-text">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.field{
  position: relative;
}

.label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 10px;
  top: 2px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  font-size: 15px;
}

input:focus ~ .label,
input:not(:focus):valid ~ .label {
  top: -6px;
}
```

Basically I want when the user writes something in the input, the label is moved over the input.

Can this be obtained only from the css?

Can you please change the example I created to understand exactly how this is done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `when the user writes something in the input` . That generates an event which you can control with javaScript but not with CSS (only ). Also the selector `input:focus ~ .label` will select the sibling ( down the DOM tree ) of the input with class `label`. `label` and `input` are not siblings. And also if they were, label is BEFORE input.

Comment: maybe I did not express myself correctly, on the event of focus, which also exists in CSS

Comment: The selector `input:focus ~ .label` will select the sibling ( down the DOM tree ) of the `input` with class `label`. `label` and `input` are not siblings. And also if they were, `label` is BEFORE `input`. You cannot select elements up the dom tree, only down.

Comment: There is no previous sibling selector nor is there a parent selector so you cannot do this with pure css and your current html structure

Comment: Please research a bit more before posting a question. [You can check this out! This might help!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942247/how-to-move-placeholder-to-top-on-focus-and-while-typing)

Comment: You can use my answer to the same question from the link below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57632830/11908502

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a transition effect up the input on change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57632607/how-to-make-a-transition-effect-up-the-input-on-change)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i hope this is what you need. but there is a problem when you unfocused input.

i just make little changes in `HTML`.

```css
.field{
  position: relative;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 10px;
  top: 2px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  font-size: 15px;
}
input:focus ~ label{
  top:-10px;
  font-size:12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
 <input type="text" class="input-text">
  <label>First Name</label>
</div>
```

Comment: you changed the html structure, can you please do the same thing but the html structure given to me remains intact? In the site that I have to develop, it is difficult to change the HTML structure

Comment: The simplest code snippet on the web for floating `placeHolder` ! :)

Answer (score 9):

**Please try this modest code**

```css
.field{
  position: relative;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 10px;
  top: 2px;
  transition: 1.2s ease all;
  font-size: 15px;
}
input:focus ~ label{
  top:-10px;
  font-size:12px;
  opacity: 1; 
 margin-left: 45px;  
 transition: all 1.5s ease-out; 
 -webkit-transform: rotate(720deg);   
 zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
 <input type="text" class="input-text">
  <label>First Name</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Hope this may help you.

Please try below code.

```css
  .field{
  position: relative;
  margin-top:20px;
}
input:focus ~ label, input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label {
  top:-13px;
  font-size:12px;
background-color: white;
}
label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 10px;
  top: 2px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <div class="control">
      <input type="text" class="input-text" placeholder=" ">
      <label>First Name</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that on focus. To detect actual typing, you need javascript.

```css
.field {
  position: relative;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 21px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.input-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 20px;
}

input:focus + label {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <input type="text" class="input-text">
  <label>First Name</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, that changes his HTML structure.

Comment: you changed the html structure, can you please do the same thing but the html structure given to me remains intact? In the site that I have to develop, it is difficult to change the HTML structure

Comment: @Cristi I'm afraid that's not an option. To manipulate the label in CSS when input is triggered, the label must be behind the input in HTML.

Comment: then we need to use javascript to solve the problem right?
Can you please fill in your example with javascript so that we get what we want?

Answer (score 2):

I post this answer to provide an additional solution.

You can make use of `translateY` and `scale` properties to achieve that effect.

```css
.field {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}

.text {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}

.input-text {
  color: white;
}

.input-text:focus+.text {
  transform: translateY(-18px) scale(0.88);
}

.input-text:focus {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <input type="text" class="input-text">
  <label class="text">First Name</label>
</div>
```

Comment: ok but if the input has text and I click outside, the label appears above the text.
How can we handle this case?

Comment: Updated my answer, check it out. @Cristi

Comment: Thanks, but now the text is hidden when I click outside. The text should be remain in input :)

Comment: @Cristi Check again :)

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid there is no way(best of my knowledge) to select parent element in `css` and here we need to select parent `div`. so i just add little `jQuery` on input focus to parent div `focused`.

I know this is not perfect solution as you need but here we only add class by jQuery.

```js
$('input').focus(function(){
  $(this).parents('.field').addClass('focused');
});

$('input').blur(function(){
  var inputValue = $(this).val();
  if ( inputValue == "" ) {
    $(this).parents('.field').removeClass('focused');  
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('filled');
  }
})
```

```css
.field{
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 10px;
  top: 2px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.focused label{
  top: -10px;
  font-size:13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" class="input-text">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 148/5000
yes, it is perfect, the case must also be addressed on the "focusout". At this point if you delete the text, the placeholder stays up, it does not return to its original form

Comment: This is the Best Answer